# Why am I getting "cannot find module" I've already tried a lot of solutions

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

This is the first time when i will install Nuxt Js after watching a lot of youtube tutorials and articles on Google, so i have already installed Node JS on my droplet based on Ubuntu 18.04 
after that i run `npm init -y`  and `npm install nuxt --save`   and `npx create-nuxt-app project` and get this error message :

```
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/root/.npm/_npx/1934/lib/node_modules/create-nuxt-app/node_modules/ejs/postinstall.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ejs@2.7.4 postinstall: `node ./postinstall.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ejs@2.7.4 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-11-28T16_17_41_163Z-debug.log
Install for create-nuxt-app@latest failed with code 1
```

Comment: Don't use npm on the root user. Try to use npm with a regular user and see if that works.

Comment: But, why as a regular user? Any specific reason?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i found the solution

```
npm i -g create-nuxt-app
npx create-nuxt-app nuxt002
npm run dev
```

Reference :https://github.com/nuxt-community/starter-template/issues/48

Answer (score 1):

similar problem with different environment . I came across this problem but it for a vue app and I solved it by removing node_modules folder and removing **yarn.lock** or **package-lock.json** file
now run `npm i` ...
it worked

Answer (score 0):

I think you are combining two separate installation instructions.

From the installation instructions mentioned here: https://nuxtjs.org/guide/installation#using-code-create-nuxt-app-code-

You don't need to run `npm init -y` and `npm install nuxt --save`

Follow these steps:

- In your terminal go to folder where you want to create your project
- Run `npx create-nuxt-app <project-name>`
- Select the options that the scaffolder provides about various packages in your project
- That's it. The packages will be installed and your project is ready.

If you don't want to use the scaffolder, then, follow this doc: https://nuxtjs.org/guide/installation#starting-from-scratch

In this case, you'll need to run `npm init -y` and `npm install nuxt --save`

Comment: that's what i do,  i create a folder called quick and i do cd quick, than i run npx create-nuxt-app quick and i get the same error

Comment: Can you run `npx -v` and `node -v` in your terminal and let me know the versions?

Comment: @Celsiuss' comment about using root user also seems like a good suggestion. Are you logged in as a root user?

Comment: npm -version : 3.5.2
npx -version : -bash: /usr/local/bin/npx: No such file or directory
node -version : v8.10.0

i'm logged as root user

Comment: You don't have npx installed. Run `npm install -g npx` and then try creating the project

Comment: i have install npx and the latest node version just now 13.x with npx 6 and i still have the same issue

Comment: Okay, so I tried creating the project as a `root` user and got the same error. So, that's where the problem is. You should log-in as a normal user and then create the project.